# How do you declare a Rake task that depends on a parameterized task?

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

I have seen examples where a task has parameters and a dependency task like:

```
task :name, [:first_name, :last_name] => [:pre_name] do |t, args|
  args.with_defaults(:first_name => "John", :last_name => "Dough")
  puts "First name is #{args.first_name}"
  puts "Last name is #{args.last_name}"
end
```

How would you pass parameters to the **name** task if it was a task dependency like:

```
task :sendLetter => :name
  #do something
end
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Args are passed down through the call stack.  You just need to make sure your top-level task captures all the arguments all of the dependencies require.  In your case you'll want to put `first_name` and `last_name` on the `send_letter` task.

Here is an example that shows named arguments defined elsewhere flowing into the dependency (even if they aren't defined in the dependency), but the argument that doesn't match the name of the top-level task argument is nil.

```
desc 'Bar'
task :bar, :nom do |task, args|
  puts "BAR NOM: #{args[:nom]}"
  puts "BAR NAME: #{args[:name]}"
end

desc 'Foo'
task :foo, [:name] => :bar do |task, args|
  puts "FOO NAME: #{args[:name]}"
end
```

Running `rake foo[baz]` yields

```
BAR NOM: 
BAR NAME: baz
FOO NAME: baz
```

It is interesting to note that using `args.with_defaults(nom: 'Jaques')` in the `foo` task has no effect on the dependent task -- `nom` is still nil.

Rake version: `rake, version 10.0.3`

Ruby version: `ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]`

Comment: Thank you, great help. But god I hope metasyntactic variables will die and good creative examples will come back.

Comment: What are metasyntactic variables, or rather, what of the above are you referring to?

Comment: I can see that defaults would not be passed because the dependencies would run before the `with_defaults` call. However, is there a good way to make this happen, other than extracting a constant for each default and manually ensuring that the `with_defaults` call is present in all dependent tasks that use the argument (or helper function call for all defaults)?

Comment: `with_defaults` doesn't change `args`, `with_defaults!` does. But yeah, it's executed after the prerequisites.

Answer (score 9):

The closest you're probably going to get is either

```
task :sendLetter do
  task(:name).invoke("first", "last")
end
```

or

```
task :sendLetter do
  task(:name).execute(["first", "last"])
end
```

You can do something like

```
task :sendLetter => task(:name).invoke("first", "last")
```

but that will invoke `name` regardless of whether you ask for `sendLetter` or not.

`Task#invoke` only calls the task if it hasn't been called and calls any uncalled prereqs first. `Task#execute` always calls the task but does not call any prereqs. Note that the parameters don't affect the call-once nature of `Task#invoke`: if you invoke a parameterized task twice, it will only get run once, whether or not the parameters are different.